# TypeError: invalid arguments to setopt in pycurl python flask API Development

Tags: python, python-requests, flask-restful, pycurl

I am trying to build a Webservice API using python flask. When I execute this code below:

```
http://localhost/Service/API/Services.svc/XMLService/Students?SEARCHBY=StudentNo&STUDENTNUMBER='1234'&SESSIONKEY=94194202323
```

...it works fine. But I could not pass `STUDENTNUMBER` to this function.

I have tried two ways:

1. Concat build a string and pass it to `c.setopt(c.URL,)` this function

   a.  Way 1
   b.  Way 2
   c.  Way 3

Via those ways I got the same error:

> TypeError: invalid arguments to `setopt`

2. Pass the variable using c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, post_data)

   a.  Way 4

   This way I got the same error:

   > Method not allowed. Please see the  for constructing valid requests to the service

   So that I am going to this link:

   b.  Way 5

   This way I got the same error

   > TypeError: invalid arguments to `setopt`

**Way 1:**

```
student_url = " http://localhost/Service/API/Services.svc/XMLService/Students?SEARCHBY=StudentNo&STUDENTNUMBER=%s&SESSIONKEY=94194202323"%student_number;
 c.setopt(c.URL,student_url)
```

**Way 2:**

```
c.setopt(c.URL,"http://localhost/Service/API/Services.svc/XMLService/Students?SEARCHBY=StudentNo&STUDENTNUMBER=%s&SESSIONKEY=94194202323"%(student_number))
```

**Way 3:**

```
c.setopt(c.URL,"http://localhost/Service/API/Services.svc/XMLService/Students?SEARCHBY=StudentNo&STUDENTNUMBER=%s&SESSIONKEY=94194202323"%student_number)
```

**Way 4:**

```
c.setopt(c.URL,"http://localhost/Service/API/Services.svc/XMLService/Students?SEARCHBY=StudentNo&STUDENTNUMBER=%s&SESSIONKEY=94194202323")
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, 'STUDENTNUMBER = 1234')
```

**Way 5:**

```
post_data ={'STUDENTNUMBER' : '1234'}
c.setopt(c.URL,"http://localhost/Service/API/Services.svc/XMLService/Students?SEARCHBY=StudentNo&SESSIONKEY=94194202323")
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, post_data)
c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be a question about Flask.  It seems you're trying to write some code to query the API (which may be Flask powered).

I suggest using the [Python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) library for this, as you can then define your parameters as a dictionary which is much easier.  **Not to be confused with `Flask.request` which is a different thing entirely!**

```
import requests
url = 'http://localhost/Service/API/Services.svc/XMLService/Students'
params = {'SEARCHBY': 'StudentNo', 
          'STUDENTNUMBER': '1234',
          'SESSIONKEY': 94194202323}
r = requests.get(url, params)
```

The last line above sends the request, and you can see the full URL with:

```
>>> print (r.url)
http://localhost/Service/API/Services.svc/XMLService/Students?SEARCHBY=StudentNo&STUDENTNUMBER=1234&SESSIONKEY=94194202323
```

Or print the response code, which is a 404 in my case:

```
>>> print(r)
<Response [404]>
```

If the response contains data you can access this through `r.text`:

```
>>> print (r.text)
I am the 404's response body.
```